# How write this code without function and make more simple in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

how can i write this code in a simple way, without function and write all in int main() ???

I need find the sum of two elements of the array as close to zero as possible in C++...

Examples:

Input:

5 1 2 3 4 5

Output:

1 2

Input:

10 -100 100 -753 999 -159 9 45 7 -8 -1

Output:

-100 100

Input:

3 0 1 -2

Output:

0 1

````
   #include <iostream>
 
void findMinSumPair(int *arr1, int arr_size)
{
  int sum, minSum, min1Pair, min2Pair;
  min1Pair = arr1[0];
  min2Pair = arr1[1];
  minSum = min1Pair + min2Pair;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < arr_size-1; i++) 
  {
    for(int j = i+1; j < arr_size; j++) 
      {
      sum = arr1[i] + arr1[j];
    }
  }
  std::cout << min1Pair << " " << min2Pair;
}

int main()
{
  int arr1[] = {-100, 100, -753, 999, -159, 9, 45, 7, -8, -1}; 
  int ctr = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    std::cout << "The given array is :  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < ctr; i++)
    {
    std::cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    } 
    std::cout << " ";
    
    std::cout << "The Pair of elements whose sum is minimum are:";
    findMinSumPair(arr1, ctr);
}

        ```
````

Comment: Hello Vardan: I dont get how you get the second part ``` Input:

10 -100 100 -753 999 -159 9 45 7 -8 -1

Output:

-100 100```

Comment: @YunfeiChen `-100 + 100 == 0`. You can't get a result closer to zero.

Comment: 1. sort the array `(O(n.log(n))` 2. find zero or sign change position `O(n)` 3. scan from that in both ways and find closest match `O(n)` if you put all together you will have `O(n.log(n))` result instead of your `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the body of the function and replace the call with this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    int arr1[] = { 0, 1, -2}; 
    int ctr = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    //------------- print original array ------------------ 
    std::printf("The given array is :  ");
    for(int i = 0; i < ctr; ++i) {
        std::printf("%d  ", arr1[i]);
    } 
    std::printf("\n");
    //------------------------------------------------------  
    std::printf("The Pair of elements whose sum is minimum are: \n");
    
    int sum = 0;
 
    if(ctr < 2)
        return 0;
    int min1Pair = arr1[0];
    int min2Pair = arr1[1];
    int minSum = min1Pair + min2Pair;
  
    for(int i = 0; i < ctr-1; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < ctr; j++) {
            sum = arr1[i] + arr1[j];
            if(abs(sum) < abs(minSum)) {
                minSum = sum;
                min1Pair = arr1[i];
                min2Pair = arr1[j];
            }
        }
    }
    std::printf("[%d, %d]\n", min1Pair, min2Pair);
    
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work this way with recursive functions and with more complex functions but in this simple case it works. You have also to replace the arguments.

`sum` wasn't initialized in the original code. This causes undefined behavior. You should always initialize your variables.

Comment: Umm copying functions and putting it into the main body is a bad idea, the purpose of functions is to increase reability, also I am pretty sure the OP wants a simpler and more elegant solution not a simple copy and paste solution.

Comment: @YunfeiChen I think OP has a problem understanding the program flow with functions and it's easier to read it from top to bottom. I tried to change as few as possible. You can give a different answer with optimized code. It will probably help.